# Camel Converting JSON to XML Not Working

Tags: java, xml, json, apache-camel

I am trying to convert JSON to XML using Apache Camel and am running into all sorts of problems.

Here is the code that should work according to the [tutorial page](http://camel.apache.org/xmljson.html) but does not:

```
// from JSON to XML
from("direct:unmarshal").unmarshal(xmlJsonFormat).to("mock:xml");
```

I have put this in a `RouteBuilder` class and overridden the `configure()` method.

When I run my code I receive a `org.apache.camel.NoSuchEndpointException`.

Does anyone know what I am missing?

Comment: Do you get an exception could you post that?

Comment: You need to add camel-xmjson to your classpath and the JARs it needs

Comment: @ClausIbsen I think this solved my problem. Now, when I run the code the program does not do anything. I am not seeing my JSON string parsed to XML. 0_o I instantiated the `XmlJsonDataFormat` class with a `HashMap`. From what I read about the API, this is one way to create an `XmlJsonDataFormat` object, - `http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/model/dataformat/XmlJsonDataFormat.html`